# Why do nmap, ss (netscan?) and lsof give different results?

Tags: networking, lsof, nmap, port, ss

I'm trying to understand which ports are actively listening (in use?) on my machine and don't really know what I'm doing. The three commands I've experimented with are `nmap`, `ss` (?`netscan`?) and `lsof`.

`netscan` reports that only 1 port is actively listening (631):

```
$ sudo nmap -sT  localhost
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-06-02 21:28 EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000094s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
631/tcp open  ipp
```

`ss` (?`netscan`?) reports 2 ports are in use (631 & 53):

```
$ sudo ss -tulwn | grep LISTEN
tcp    LISTEN  0       4096     127.0.0.53%lo:53           0.0.0.0:*            
tcp    LISTEN  0       5            127.0.0.1:631          0.0.0.0:*            
tcp    LISTEN  0       5                [::1]:631             [::]:*
```

Finally, if I check individual ports with `lsof -i:xx`, I see results for 631 & 53, but also for ports 80 & 443:

```
$ sudo lsof -i:80

COMMAND  PID       USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox 3481 me   74u  IPv4  85172      0t0  TCP Machine:56024->lga25s63-in-f3.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)

$ sudo lsof -i:443
COMMAND    PID       USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
skypeforl 2426 me   27u  IPv4  77133      0t0  TCP Machine:60396->13.83.65.43:https (ESTABLISHED)
skypeforl 2453 me   72u  IPv4  56536      0t0  TCP Machine:58945->40.86.187.166:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   3481 me   95u  IPv4  81375      0t0  TCP Machine:53788->104.16.249.249:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   3481 me  157u  IPv4  80283      0t0  TCP Machine:49080->lga34s15-in-f5.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome-gn 3799 me   74u  IPv4  55080      0t0  TCP Machine:42196->server-52-85-61-100.ewr53.r.cloudfront.net:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
chrome-gn 3799 me   95u  IPv4  55072      0t0  TCP Machine:43998->104.16.248.249:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

I had thought these three commands were basically different views of the same information. Why are some ports only revealed by some of these commands?

Answer (score 3):

Starting with the difference between `ss` and `nmap`. For port 53, the reason is the difference between `localhost` and the other 16 million addresses reserved for the local machine. `127.0.0.1` is not the same as `127.0.0.53`. `ss` is reporting all the ports for the local machine whilst `nmap` is restricting itself to the address 127.0.0.1.

As for the extra reports from `lsof`, this is looking for something very different. Your `ss` and `nmap` commands are looking for sockets in `LISTEN` state, i.e. waiting for incoming connections. Your `lsof` is looking for all sockets, in particular this includes any established connections and connections which have been torn down. You are looking for things where **either** end is using port 80 or **either** end is using port 443.

So the punchline is these 3 commands show different things because your belief that these are showing the same information is incorrect. This is an apple to orange to banana comparison. 3 different commands show different information because they show different information.

Comment: Also nmap will only scan most common 1000 ports by default.

Comment: Super good answer. Interested in understanding the numbers behind the 16M addresses you mention. What address range is reserved for local machine? Always thought of localhost just as 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Kiteloopdesign The 127.0.0.0/8 address space is reserved for the local machine, which gives you 2^24 addresses of which 2 (127.255.255.255 and 127.0.0.0) are reserved for the broadcast and network addresses leaving you with 16,777,214 addresses. As a concrete example if you are running a modern systemd based system you may well find that /etc/resolv.conf lists the nameserver as running on 127.0.0.53.